# Matlab import data from file with multiple-space delimiter

Tags: matlab, import, whitespace, delimiter

I have to import some data from a text file to work with it in Matlab:

```
1947/02/28   79,1
1947/03/31   79,1
1947/04/30   80,2
```

and so on...

My problem is: I cant import it to a 35x2 matrix (35 is just a random number) or a struct that contains at one hand a 35x1 matrix(of string or date-time) and on the other hand a 35x1 matrix(of double)

I dont find a import function like textscan, importdata ... which supports more than one space and otherwise it tries to split the data at the ",".

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume `fid` is your file handle.

```
r = struct('date', {}, 'value', {});
n_line = 0;
tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    tok = regexp(tline, '(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(\d+),(\d)', 'tokens');
    if ~isempty(tok)
        n_line = n_line + 1;
        r(n_line).date = datenum(tok{1}{1});
        r(n_line).value = 0.1 * str2double(tok{1}{3}) + str2double(tok{1}{2});
    end
    tline = fgets(fid);
end
```

And don't forget to close the `fid` when you are done. I am assuming that you consider `80,2` to be something like a German notation for `80.2`, not sure if that's correct.

Comment: Thank you!
Thats near the way I wanted it, with a little transposing and such thing's I will get my wish-matrix. :)